# Regex allowing 3 numbers with no special characters and space

Tags: javascript

I am using a regex as /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?$/ which allow only 3 numbers and no special characters

I need to include space check as well.
Please help me

Comment: You might checkout http://jsregex.rcode5.com/ - it lets you play with javascript regex.   Where exactly do you need the spaces?  Maybe you can give a sample of possible input strings and what you're expecting to get out.

Comment: Give us examples of strings you are supposed to accept and strings you want rejected.

Comment: "I need to include space check as well," doesn't tell me what you're looking for.  Do you want to allow spaces?  Disallow them?  Allow them only in particular spots?  Apply to NASA?  What?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your regular expression is so complex. If you need three digits with no other characters, just use this:

```
/^[0-9]{3}$/
```

That will only validate strings that are three digits with nothing else, "324", "857", "111". You get it.

If you have other requirements, please update your question with them.

Comment: I have a textbox where i need to put only numeric value that can be 1 to 3 numbers and no space and special characters so I used the above regex but still it is taking space.

Please see below line of code snippet.

 return that.optional(element)  || ((/^\d{1,3}$/.test(value)) && (Number(value) >= 0)) 
Also, is it because of that.optional(element), does this allow space?

Comment: one to three numbers would just be /^[0-9]{1-3}$/

Comment: The regex is so complex because it seems designed to accept much more complex strings than described, including such things as "-1,650,763".  But I don't really know what it is the OP really wants.

Comment: /^[0-9]{1-3}$/ still allow space when used as

Comment: return that.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{1-3}$/